# Send command or data to USB port from PC to Android device through terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, terminal, echo

After much research, unfortunately I couldn't find any solution to my problem and I'm in a bit of a pinch here since I don't know much how this goes, the problem is this:

I have to send a string or command to an android tablet yes or yes via USB cable in which said device will receive it and display something on the screen, after much research I found I could use the `echo` command to send it on the Ubuntu terminal, but since I'm fairly new to the OS I don't know much how to do this.

Basically most of my research converges in that I have to find the USB port in which the tablet is connected to, the problem is that I can't find it since is connected via MTP and most of the solution say I got to find something like `/dev/ttyUSB0` for example and in my case, I can't see any of that through `lsusb`, all I know is that the tablet is connected in `usb 1-6` but I can't find a way to make a correlation or send a simple string of "hello world" to this tablet, followed something like [this answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117037/how-to-send-data-to-a-serial-port-and-see-any-answer) but the console says the following

```
echo -ne '\033[2J' > /dev/bus/usb/001/003
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

And I can't really do the steps [here either](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184526/how-to-get-bus-and-device-relationship-for-a-dev-ttyusb) 'cause `/dev/ttyUS0` isn't listed at all...

So in the end, how do I send an echo to the port where my Android tablet is?

**Info that might be useful:**

1. After a quick `lsusb`, the tablet info is this one

   ```
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID fff0:05d1
   ```
2. Further info in this device is the following:

   ```
   lsusb -v -d fff0:05d1

   Bus 001 Device 003: ID fff0:05d1  
   Device Descriptor:
     bLength                18
     bDescriptorType         1
     bcdUSB               2.00
     bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
     bDeviceSubClass         0 
     bDeviceProtocol         0 
     bMaxPacketSize0        64
     idVendor           0xfff0 
     idProduct          0x05d1 
     bcdDevice            2.33
     iManufacturer           2 USB Developer
     iProduct                3 Android
     iSerial                 4 871c9c67c66700000000
     bNumConfigurations      1
     Configuration Descriptor:
       bLength                 9
       bDescriptorType         2
       wTotalLength           62
       bNumInterfaces          2
       bConfigurationValue     1
       iConfiguration          0 
       bmAttributes         0xc0
         Self Powered
       MaxPower              224mA
       Interface Descriptor:
         bLength                 9
         bDescriptorType         4
         bInterfaceNumber        0
         bAlternateSetting       0
         bNumEndpoints           3
         bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
         bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
         bInterfaceProtocol      0 
         iInterface              5 MTP
         Endpoint Descriptor:
           bLength                 7
           bDescriptorType         5
           bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
           bmAttributes            2
             Transfer Type            Bulk
             Synch Type               None
             Usage Type               Data
           wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
           bInterval               0
         Endpoint Descriptor:
           bLength                 7
           bDescriptorType         5
           bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
           bmAttributes            2
             Transfer Type            Bulk
             Synch Type               None
             Usage Type               Data
           wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
           bInterval               0
         Endpoint Descriptor:
           bLength                 7
           bDescriptorType         5
           bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
           bmAttributes            3
             Transfer Type            Interrupt
             Synch Type               None
             Usage Type               Data
           wMaxPacketSize     0x001c  1x 28 bytes
           bInterval               6
       Interface Descriptor:
         bLength                 9
         bDescriptorType         4
         bInterfaceNumber        1
         bAlternateSetting       0
         bNumEndpoints           2
         bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
         bInterfaceSubClass     66 
         bInterfaceProtocol      1 
         iInterface              0 
         Endpoint Descriptor:
           bLength                 7
           bDescriptorType         5
           bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
           bmAttributes            2
             Transfer Type            Bulk
             Synch Type               None
             Usage Type               Data
           wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
           bInterval               0
         Endpoint Descriptor:
           bLength                 7
           bDescriptorType         5
           bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
           bmAttributes            2
             Transfer Type            Bulk
             Synch Type               None
             Usage Type               Data
           wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
           bInterval               0
   Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
     bLength                10
     bDescriptorType         6
     bcdUSB               2.00
     bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
     bDeviceSubClass         0 
     bDeviceProtocol         0 
     bMaxPacketSize0        64
     bNumConfigurations      1
   Device Status:     0x0001
     Self Powered
   ```